# Assigning macro to multiple check boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Check Boxes (Form Controls) located in the same sheet. When I click on any Check Box, I need it to hide a specified range of rows and 2 specified scroll bars.

I had initially used an Active Control Check Box, and written this code which worked (This worked specifically for CheckBox1):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
[105:112].EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scroll Bar 79").Visible = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scroll Bar 82").Visible = False

Else: 
[105:112].EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scroll Bar 79").Visible = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Scroll Bar 82").Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

However, I want to create a more generic code because I have 60 of these checkboxes(as described below).
This code has four variables: 1) Check Box Name 2) Row Range 3)Scroll Bar 1 4)Scroll Bar 2

For each check box in the sheet, I want to be able to alter the 4 variable names. I have tried using this format 'NameOfMacro "variable1", "variable2"' when assigning macros to each of the checkboxes but this hasn't worked!

```
Sub Hide ()

Dim chkBox As CheckBox
Dim RowRange As Range
Dim SB1 As Shape
Dim SB2 As Shape

Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

If chkBox.Value = True Then
    [RowRange].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SB1").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SB2").Visible = False
Else:
    [RowRange].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SB1").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("SB2").Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

I am having trouble on two fronts

1)Creating a generic macro, I get errors such as "unable to get the checkboxes property of the worksheet class". How can I make the check box name variable?
2) Assigning the same macro to multiple checkboxes while being able to alter the arguements using this method: 'NameOfMacro "variable1", "variable2"'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What code did you actually try to assign the macros? It's not really a good idea to use parameters with `OnAction` so it would be better if you could include something in the checkbox names, or use a lookup table.

Comment: I tried to assign the sub "Hide" to all check boxes. 
For each check box I want to then be able to amend Row Range, SB1 and SB2 when assigning the macro. I have seen this type of suggestion come up several times: 'NameOfMacro "variable1", "variable2"'. Unfortunately doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Typical approaches include giving each checkbox a specific name which can be used to determine the items to be operated on - you can hard-code these in the common macro or use (for example) a lookup table on a hidden sheet to get their names from the checkbox name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a parameter for your `Hide` routine. Then pass the value of the checkbox in to that parameter. This will give you the behavior you want. Just make one of these for each checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    HideRow CheckBox1.Value, ActiveSheet.Range("A105:A112"), "Scroll Bar 79", "Scroll Bar 82"
End Sub

Public Sub HideRow(ByVal hiding As Boolean, ByVal rowRange As Range, ByVal ScrollBarOne As String, ByVal ScrollBarTwo As String)
    If hiding Then
        rowRange.EntireRow.hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ScrollBarOne).Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ScrollBarTwo).Visible = False
    Else
        rowRange.EntireRow.hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ScrollBarOne).Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ScrollBarTwo).Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: On what line?  ?

Comment: HideRow CheckBox1.Value, ActiveSheet.Row("105:112"), "Scroll Bar 79", "Scroll Bar 82"

Comment: Maybe it's the .Row try it with a .Range (See my edit above)

Comment: Perfect! Works! Thank you so much. VBA novice here. Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Great! Click the upvote arrow and the green checkmark if this solves your question. That will close it out so people don't come by trying to help.

Comment: I just tried the code with multiple checkboxes, my code is as follows:     
Private Sub CBP2Q1_Click()
HideRow CBP2Q1.Value, ActiveSheet.Range("105:110"), "P2Q1_SCA", "P2Q1_SCB"
End Sub
Private Sub CBP2Q2_Click()
HideRow CBP2Q2.Value, ActiveSheet.Range("115:120"), "P2Q2_SCA", "P2Q2_SCB"
End Sub       

If I click one checkbox, the other checkbox gets checked as well.

Comment: The code doesn't control what checkbox gets checked. You have some issue with your form or controls. Please open a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Wouldn't this be controlled by each Private Sub? Since each CheckBox has its own Private Sub?

Comment: You CAN change a checkbox state with code. You ARE NOT with the code you have shown. This is a different question.